# Git: If given a commit SHA, can I fetch the previous one?

Tags: git, bash, shell, scripting

My purpose here is to write a script to rebase right before the commit provided so that it's easy to fix-up a commit by providing the SHA (long term thinking of allowing the user to provide a regexp but you get the point).

Any creative solutions? Using bash here.

Comment: given a sha1 `abcdef`, you can access the previous one using simply `abcdef^` (for example `git show abcdef^`)

Comment: Be aware that they're may be multiple *previous ones*; a commit can have more than one parent.

Answer (score 2):

From the gitrevisions man page:

> ^, e.g. HEAD^, v1.5.1^0
>
> A suffix ^ to a revision parameter means the first parent of that commit object. ^ means the th parent (i.e. ^ is equivalent to ^1). As a special rule, ^0 means the commit itself and is used when  is the object name of a tag object that refers to a commit object.
>
> ~, e.g. master~3
>
> A suffix ~ to a revision parameter means the commit object that is the th generation ancestor of the named commit object, following only the first parents. I.e. ~3 is equivalent to ^^^ which is equivalent to ^1^1^1. See below for an illustration of the usage of this form.

So both `rev^` and `rev~` are the (first) parent revision of a commit. As @Jubobs says in his comment however any given revision can have more than one parent.